# Why is passing by reference slower in this code?

Tags: php

I've encountered something that seems like a strange performance problem. Running this code:

```
<?php

function test_ref(&$test)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    {
        $foo = "s" . rand(1, 1000);
        if (!array_key_exists($foo, $test))
        {
            $test[$foo] = array();
        }
        $test[$foo][] = rand(1, 10);
    }
}

function test()
{
    $test = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    {
        $foo = "s" . rand(1, 1000);
        if (!array_key_exists($foo, $test))
        {
            $test[$foo] = array();
        }
        $test[$foo][] = rand(1, 10);
    }

    return $test;
}

$scriptstart = microtime(true);
$test = array();
test_ref($test);
$sum = 0;

foreach ($test as $key => $val)
{
    foreach ($val as $val2)
    {
        $sum += $val2;
    }
}

echo "sum " . $sum . "<br>";
$scriptelapsed = microtime(true) - $scriptstart;
echo "time taken " . $scriptelapsed . "<br>";

$scriptstart = microtime(true);
$test = test();
$sum = 0;

foreach ($test as $key => $val)
{
    foreach ($val as $val2)
    {
        $sum += $val2;
    }
}

echo "sum " . $sum . "<br>";
$scriptelapsed = microtime(true) - $scriptstart;
echo "time taken " . $scriptelapsed . "<br>";

?>
```

I get these results:

```
sum 548521
time taken 12.37544798851
sum 551236
time taken 0.29530310630798
```

What's going on here? It seems to be connected to the fact that I insert sub-arrays into the array, though I don't see why passing by reference should be that much slower.

(this is on PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin Patch 0.9.9.1)

(edit: fixed using of unset variables, still the same result)

Comment: Where does `$array` come from?

Comment: Returning by value isn't free.

Comment: I don't know the answer (but I would be interested in knowing it), but I would note that references in PHP are not pointers. They are in fact a level of indirection. So by using a reference, the interpreter must first look up the reference, then look up the referred value. Without references, it's one step less. This might be the cause of the slowdown you're seeing here.

Comment: It probably has something to do with all the undefined variable notices this generates

Comment: Amazing (and almost identical) results if you replace `array_key_exists` with `isset`.

Comment: Fixed the mistyped variable name, still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing values from another scope - that's always slower than only using ones that are defined within the function itself. Here's a nice blog post explaining it, even though that's not its primary topic: [PHP internals: When does foreach copy?](http://nikic.github.com/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is just my guess but I think we could explain it like this:

- when using no reference a local variable is created (that is directly pointing to a memory) and the loop goes like:

  - $i = 0; $foo = 499; $test[499] = array(); $test[499][] = 2; "commit" directly to a memory
  - finaly, the value $test is then returned - reading directly from the memory pointer
- when using referenced value, the variable passed is like a pointer to a pointer (that is finally pointing to a memory)

  - in this case the loop looks like:
  - $i = 0; $foo = 354; $test[354] = array(); $test[354][] = 7; "commit" to a memory via pointer to a memory pointer

I guess therefore there is at least one more step neccessary when working with referenced variables...